# How can I use ansible to script eclipse installation and configuration?

Tags: eclipse, ansible

I am an ansible newbee, so please forgive if this is obvious or well covered elsewhere.

I want to script the setup of a developer virtual machine using Vagrant. Part of the task is to install (simple) and configure eclipse (i.e. install plugins and features, import formatting settings and other workspace configurations etc. -- not so simple).

I could use the shell provisioner plus some scripts that automate the eclipse setup. Or I could try to use the ansible provisioner. Can ansible help me here? Are there any ansible modules that provide solutions for standard eclipse setup tasks?

Of course I could create a suitable eclipse installation manually and then pack and distribute that. In order to make this repeatable I would need to document all the steps and make sure that this documentation is complete. This is not what I want to do. I want to script the installation process so that it can be repeated and extended at any time.

Comment: I've worked at a place where they tried the "manually create a custom Eclipse and distribute that" approach. It sort-of worked (didn't include importing project sets), but was a nightmare to maintain and resulted in everyone who used it being trapped in old versions of Eclipse and plug-ins. Everyone, including it's creator, hated the thing.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of an external, generic tool like Ansible, you could use [Eclipse Oomph](http://www.eclipse.org/oomph) to configure an Eclipse installation and workspace for the VMs. Oomph is the technology behind [Eclipse's own installer](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer), but it's designed to be a generic configuration management tool for any Eclipse-based "products." There's a learning curve, but one of Oomph's stated purposes is to support the situation you're facing. For starters, see the [Oomph Authoring Guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring).

Comment: Just scanned the Oomph documentation. Do I understand correctly that this would result in a customized installation procedure that our developers would have to execute inside their VMs? Or is there a way to execute the installer from a script (In headless mode, i.e. ssh login to the VM without an X display available)?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I think Oomph can be executed headless, based on this discussion from 1 year ago: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/782061/ . That discussion isn't specifically about using Oomph as an installer, but is still relevant to Oomph running headless.

Comment: Probably best to ask the specific question about the current state of headless Oomph on the forum: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/287/

Comment: Eclipse has it's own forums. The Oomph group is here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/287/

Answer (score 3):

The following ansible role installs Eclipse + plugins: https://github.com/AlbanAndrieu/ansible-eclipse

The maintainer also provide a docker container to run the generated eclipse installation (without installing ansible locally).